# Need some help on optimizing 301 redirects in nginx

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I just created a new structure for a website, and I need some help on redirecting to new places.

The code that works is here, but I guess this can be optimized a lot.

```
location = /nl {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name permanent;
}

location = /nl/ {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name permanent;
}

location = /en {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name permanent;
}

location = /en/ {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name permanent;
}

location = /nl/contact {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name/contact/ permanent;
}

location = /en/contact {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name/contact/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Rewrites don't have to be in location blocks - and can match against a regex. Very roughly (untested, not fully thought through, and regex isn't my forte) you may have some success with two rewrites: `rewrite ^/(en|nl)/contact$ $scheme://$server_name/contact/ permanent;` and 
`rewrite ^/(en|nl)(/.*)$ $scheme://$server_name permanent;` order does matter in this case. Alternatively, you can combine the first 4 and last 2 location blocks with regex matches - but that does chance the matching priority (which may not be very significant).

Comment: Nice, it actually works without the location blocks. I had to change the code a little tho, the final working code is: `rewrite ^/(en|nl)(/?)$ $scheme://$server_name permanent; rewrite ^/(en|nl)(/contact)(/?)$ $scheme://$server_name/contact/ permanent;` Can you add this as an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: Added as an answer - thanks for the improvements (the /.* was a combination of carelessness (missing the ?) and a misinterpretation (that all files below the directory should be rewritten); but I don't think I would have caught the trailing slash on contact). You may not need `/contact` in brackets though - which might improve performance a tad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrites don't have to be in location blocks - and can match against a regex.

You may have some success with two rewrites:

```
rewrite ^/(en|nl)(/contact)(/?)$ $scheme://$server_name/contact/ permanent;
rewrite ^/(en|nl)(/?)$ $scheme://$server_name permanent;
```

Alternatively, you can combine the first 4 and last 2 location blocks with regex matches - but that does chance the matching priority (which may not be very significant).

(Credit to @Saif Bechan for fixing my original proposition)

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. By the way, I have been looking at your, and are you the ownser of the website? I actually used the article on how to set up php-fpm with nginx properly on an EC2 instance. Really good. I have one question tho, do you have any recommendation on how to set up the nginx / php-fpm environment in terms of users and file permissions. I now run an environment where sites are located in `/home/myuser/sites` and both nginx and php-fpm have `group` and `owner` set to `myuser` which is completely unsafe. Still devel environment tho, no public access.

Comment: If you are referring to the site linked in my profile, the yes, I am its owner (and it does run on EC2). Glad someone found that article useful - it is a bit outdated now that php-fpm is available from the amzn repository though. My setup has users and sites. /var/www/users/{user_name}/{domain} (and for simplicity, /var/www/{domain} is symlinked. Under each {domain} is a /public_html folder. Each {domain} runs as its own php-fpm user (e.g. web1, web2, etc.). Files are owned by the php-fpm user, and group is set to the client (e.g. web1:cyberx86); Permissions are 644.

Comment: I was referring to link in your profile. Saw an interesting article on apachebench also, will check that out in the next few weeks. Ok the looks quite good, I think I will implement the same system. One thing, what is the setup for nginx? Maybe you can write an article on this subject, because I haven't seen many of those around. And since it is quite a big step to do a proper chroot with nginx and php-fom this setup will be ideal for users.

Comment: Just to add a couple more points here - each php-fpm pool listens on a different port; allowed-clients is restricted to localhost only; there is a php_open_basedir restriction in effect; and suhosin is installed; you should also chroot each pool. I do try to improve things whenever I come across something new and interesting - but so far, I haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: I will certainly think about it - I enjoy playing around with servers - but my notes don't always make it into an article (I still have notes on building a server cluster from the summer that are sitting on my computer). I am tempted to try out a more formal benchmark on varnish vs. nginx - but I'll certainly add an article on nginx to my todo list as well.

Comment: I will follow the blog to see what the updates are. I have one final question tho. You say you use a different port for each pool, why do you do that? And if you use unix sockets, would you also create a different socket for each pool?

Comment: The reason is that under nginx, each virtualhost corresponds to one php-fpm pool. Since I have a different owner (e.g. web1, web2, etc) for the files on each virtualhost (i.e. domain/subdomain), php-fpm must run as the corresponding user, and each domain therefore gets its own php-fpm pool. Sockets or ports would be the same - you can only have one pool per socket/port. (I'd suggest sockets may be more efficient than ports, but ports set the framework for a more scalable architecture - i.e. a cluster).